# How to have an onClick event fire for certain radio button children of a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table row inside of a table. Inside this table row I have 4 buttons. I want to use jquery to fire an `onClick` for any button in the row except for the 1st one. Is there an easy way to select the `<tr>` itself instead of recreating an `onClick` for every button?

```
<table class="table table-striped stickeyHeaders">
    <tr id="buttonRow">
        <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="1"/>     
        <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="2"/>     
        <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="3"/>     
        <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="4"/>     
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my general though process but need some help to flesh it out all the way

```
$('#buttonRow').children("Some Filter that says value > 1").On('Click, function({}));
```

Comment: :not(:first-child) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:gt` selector to avoid the first element:

```js
$('#buttonRow').find(":radio:gt(0)").on('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped stickeyHeaders">
  <tr id="buttonRow">
    <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedStoreRoles" class="store-privs" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `:not` and `:first-child` pseudo-classes

```
$('#buttonRow')
  .children('td:not(:first-child)')
  .children('input')
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log(this)
  })
```